# What are some methods to hiding API keys in a RN/Expo app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, google-maps, expo

I have a RN/Expo app, paired with an AWS server, that uses API Keys, Google Maps for example, and was informed it's best practice to "hide API Keys in config files to protect against theft."

How do I go about doing this?

Is it as simple as putting the key into a specific file and then importing to where I would call the key?

Comment: Have a look [this](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/)

Comment: In addition to hiding keys in config files, you can also set [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restricting-api-keys) to your Google Maps API keys for it to be protected to unwanted usage.